# Phonegap unable to convert HTML5 mobile application to IOS

Tags: android, ios, html, mobile, cordova

I developed a project Mobile Application on Dreamweaver CS6 using HTML5, CSS3 and AJAX. When I am uploading my project on Phonegap, it is converting the app only in android and windows and showing errors in IOS and Blackberry. What could be the problem. Right now I have just use the basic theme of CS6.

Comment: what is your error boy?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you need a developer account for iOS and from there you will download certificates and signing identities, using which you can produce an ipa file, an apk equivalent for iOS applications. however the developer account costs different for different users, visit developer website for apple.